# Schema is not defined (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting Schema not defined for Schema.Types options

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const mineralSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    larry: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    specimen: {
        type:        {type: String, lowercase: true},                // thumbnail, miniature, display
        matrix:      {type: String, lowercase: true},              
        color:       {type: String, lowercase: true},
        location:    {type: String, lowercase: true},
        mine:        {type: String, lowercase: true},
        pocket:      {type: String, lowercase: true},              
        size:        Schema.Types.Mixed, 
        weight:      Number,
        comments:    Schema.Types.Mixed,
        description: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        purch_date:  {type: Date, default: Date.now },
        purch_price: Number,
        supplier:    Schema.Types.Mixed,
        images:      String
    }
});
```

I thought maybe this was a scope issue due to nested objects, but even larry is having issues.
Can I have some help please?

```
Node.js v19.7.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
C:\Users\xxx.xxx.xxx\app.js:14
    larry: Schema.Types.Mixed,
           ^

ReferenceError: Schema is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\xxx\app.js:14:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v19.7.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you try putting `mongoose.Schema.types.Mixed` for each one you have? That may fix the problem as in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#type-key) it was shown like that.

Comment: You're a wizard Harry

Comment: I saw this example on the same page..

mixed:   Schema.Types.Mixed,
_someId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
decimal: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
  ofMixed: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
  ofObjectId: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],

Comment: Do you care to share the different and when they should be used?

Comment: Do you mean the difference between `Schema.types.Mixed` and `mongoose.Schema.types.Mixed`? `Schema.types.Mixed` is saying to the computer, "find the Schema object, find the types property, and find the Mixed property in it. However, `Schema` is not an object you have in your code. `Schema` is an object that does exist in the `mongoose` library.

Comment: So, saying `mongoose.Schema.types.Mixed` says to the computer, "Find the mongoose library, get the Schema object, find the types property, and find the Mixed property in it. And that does exist within the `mongoose` library so that works.

Comment: oh okay, my minimal knowledge here made me think it would have been inherited through being within mongoose.Schema, ty